# Socket closed exception

Tags: java, sockets, exception, bufferedreader

I wrote a simple server and client example as below .

Client :

- Open a connection
- Get outputstream , write to stream and close the output stream
- Get inputstream and read from the stream. Getting exception at this point

  ```
  public class DateServer {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
  Socket client = null;
  try {
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6013);
      while (true) {
          client = serverSocket.accept();
          OutputStream outputStream = client.getOutputStream();
          InputStream inputStream = client.getInputStream();

          System.out.println("" + outputStream + "-" + inputStream);

          BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                  new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

          String line = null;
          while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
              System.out
                      .println("Message recieved from client ::" + line);
          }

          PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStream, true);

          printWriter.println(new java.util.Date().toString());

          client.close();
      }
  } catch (IOException exception) {
      exception.printStackTrace();
      System.err.println(exception);
  }
      }

      }
  ```

Client :

```
    public class DateClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException,
        IOException, InterruptedException {
    Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6013);
    OutputStream outputStream = sock.getOutputStream();
    InputStream inputStream = sock.getInputStream();

    System.out.println("" + outputStream + "-" + inputStream);

    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStream, true);
    printWriter.println("Hi Server");

    outputStream.close();

    System.out.println(sock.isConnected());

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) { // Exception 
        System.out.println(line);
    }

}

}
```

Getting  below socket closed exception in Client . Could you please let me know what would be the reason.

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:146)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:282)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:324)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:176)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:153)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:316)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:379)
at edu.iub.cs.httpserver.DateClient.main(DateClient.java:32)
```

Answer (score 14):

java.net.SocketException socket is closed
This exception means that you closed the socket, and then continued to try to use it.

```
os.close();
```

And you closed it here. Closing either the input or the output stream of a Socket closes the other stream and the Socket.

Comment: But `System.out.println(sock.isConnected());` is printing true

Comment: @Abhilash Irrelevant. `isConnected()` tells you whether you ever connected the `Socket.` ***Not*** whether it is now connected. (The `isConnected()` and `isClosed()` methods are about the state of the *socket,* not the state of the connection.)

Answer (score 4):

`java.net.SocketException` arises only when u close the `OutputStream` (or) Socket before reading from the server.

From your code, remove:

```
OutputStream.close();
```

and then try..

Comment: Thanks for the info, you saves my time :)